# ORA-12541: TNS:no listener

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, database-administration

I am working in Oracle 12c. Entering username and password in SQL Plus, it shows the error `ORA-12541: TNS:no listener`. But `listener.ora` file is present in correct path and in services there are no listener services. What do I need to do to get listener in `services.msc`?

Comment: Check whether the listener is running or not? You can check it from services.msc. Service name will be something like: "OracleOraDb10g_home1TNSListener" OR, check by running the command: "lsnrctl status"

Answer (score 0):

Since you said that there is no listener service, it sounds like it isn't even installed.  Therefore, you can install the listener by running the Oracle Net Configuration Assistant by either:

1)  Running netca from a command prompt (provided %oracle_home%\bin is in the path directory environment variable).

2)  Run netca.bat from %oracle_home%\bin

3)  Locate Oracle Net Configuration Assistant on the start menu.

Netca is pretty straightforward with only a few different dialog options (for most installations, leaving the options as default is usually best and preferred).  A good screen by screen installation via Netca can be found [here](http://www.dbaglobe.com/2013/12/oracle-database-12c-listener-creation.html).